# Is it possible to create these three different layouts with CSS using the same underlying HTML structure?

Tags: html, css

I have to create a name-value list in HTML. (Actually they are form elements, `label` and `input`)

How do I build this output so that a web designer can create the following three different layouts without changing the original HTML structure?

Variant 1:

```
Name One:
Value One

Name Two:
Value Two
```

Variant 2:

```
Name One:         Value One
Longer Name Two:  Value Two
```

Variant 3:

```
       Name One:  Value One
Longer Name Two:  Value Two
```

Creating an output for variant 2 and 3 alone would be trivial, I'd just use a table and the alignment is changed with CSS.

But how do I do it when I want to allow all three variants? How would the CSS code look like? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use a DL list, eg:

```
<dl>
   <dt>Name One:</dt>
   <dd>Value One</dd>
   <dt>Name Two:</dt>
   <dd>Value Two</dd>
   <dt>Name Three:</dt>
   <dd>Value Three</dd>
</dl>
```

and style using (roughly):

Example 1:

```
dl dt { }
dl dd { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Example 2:

```
dl dt { display: block; float: left; width: 150px; clear:left; }
dl dd { display: block; float: left; }
```

Example 3:

```
dl dt {display: block; float: left; width: 150px; text-align: right; clear:left; }
dl dd {display: block; float: left; }
```

... and it's semantic.

Comment: a big +1 for a semantic solution. The dl dt dd structure is exactly the correct element to use for a name value list.

Comment: I do have to say that the display:block properties are redundant since dt and dd are already block elements

Comment: I've tested your code and that way examples 2 and 3 don't work. I had to add "clear: left" to "dt" and remove the "clear: right" from dd. Perhaps you can double-check it and then change your code or not. Thanks!

Comment: Done. It's same old. You'd think it would work like that and then browsers act otherwise.

Oh and about the display:block; I do have a habit of being verbose in my CSS!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible and you can find lots of great examples (which you could copy!) at [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).

Comment: Wow, that's a great site! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <label for="Name" class="label">Name:</label>
   <input id="Name" name="Name" />
</div>
<div class="container">
   <label for="LongName" class="label">Long Name:</label>
   <input id="LongName" name="LongName" />
</div>
```

CSS1:

```
.container {}
.label
{
   display: block;
}
```

CSS2:

```
.container
{
   margin-left: 12em;
}

.label
{
   float: left;
   margin-left: -12em;
}
```

CSS3:

```
.container
{
    margin-left: 8em;
}

.label
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8em;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find whenever I have to do something like this is that the left side of the list (such as examples 2 and 3) is that there is no way (or at least I don´t know any) of letting both columns have a variable width.

This is specially an issue when data to be showed in the first column is variable (i.e. not labels) or comes in different languages.

If neither of those are a problem for you, then solution using DL´s from Program.X should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I build one CSS Form Framework called [Formy](http://code.google.com/p/formy-css-framework/). All 3 variants are included without changing any HTML.

Examples:

1. [Variant1](http://www.allapis.com/formy/vertical-form.html)
2. [Variant2](http://www.allapis.com/formy/horizontal-form.html)
3. [Variant3](http://www.allapis.com/formy/horizontal-form1.html)